# How to escape reserved word (keyword) in InterSystems Caché SQL?

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems

I have a column named `Date` in SQL table, but unfortunately this query throws an error:

```
select Author, Date, Text from Tiny.Comment
```

I've tried to escape the `Date` keyword with `[Date]` or `'Date'` but this never worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In InterSystems Caché SQL it's a bit different: you need to use [double quotes](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_reservedwords) symbol to escape a keyword:

```
select Author, "Date", Text from Tiny.Comment
```

This will also work:

```
select Author, myTable."Date", Text from Tiny.Comment as myTable where "Date"='2017-11-03 11:09:28'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use %STRING function like:

```
SELECT ID, Super 
FROM %Dictionary.CompiledClass 
WHERE %STRING(Super) %STARTSWITH %STRING('Base.%')
```